# series of decomposition GL

Tags: abstract-algebra

To determine the number of group composition $$GL (3, F_5) $$ where $ F_5$ is a field with five elements. What are the factors of decomposition?.

*definition*:

A series of decomposition is a series of suggrupos of $ G $ as follows:
$G = G_0\supset G_1\supset \dots\supset G_r = 1 $ where $ G_ {i +1} \ {g_i \triangleleft} $ for all $ i $ and $ \displaystyle \frac {g_i} {G_ {i +1}} $ is simple for all $ i$.
I hope any suggestions. Thank you.

Comment: Your post is almost unreadable (OK, it's better now), but I think you are asking for the composition factors of ${\rm GL}(3,5)$. One of these is the simple group ${\rm PSL}(3,5)$, and there are two further factors, both of order $2$. In fact ${\rm GL}(3,5)$ is a direct product of ${\rm PSL}(3,5)$ and a cyclic group of order $4$.